# Абстрактные классы и init

Tags: ооп, kotlin

```
abstract class AbstractClass {
    abstract fun loadData()

    init {
        loadData()
    }
}

class MyClass(
    val text: String
) : AbstractClass() {
    override fun loadData() {
        logInfo("$text")
    }

}
```

есть вот такой код. создаю класс `MyClass("привет")` но в логи получаю null

первое решение, какое пришло в голову:

```
abstract class AbstractClass {
    abstract fun loadData()

    fun init(){
        loadData()
    }
}

class MyClass(
    val text: String
) : AbstractClass() {
    override fun loadData() {
        logInfo("$text")
    }
    init {
        super.init()
    }

}
```

но оно мне не нравится.
какие есть еще варианты решения?

Comment: *"какие есть еще варианты решения?"* - убрать из `AbstractClass.init` вызов абстрактного метода. Вызывайте их строго после завершения инициализации.

Comment: @user7860670 если я убери из конструктора `MyClass` переменную `text` и напишу `logInfo("привет")` - все работает как надо.

Comment: @user7860670 верно ответил, но может что отсюда вас натолкнет на решение. https://stackoverflow.com/q/50222139/5479247